# DataObjects::ConnectionError after ruby upgrade(to 2.1.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, data-objects

```
DataObjects::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'user'@'password' (using password: YES)

from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@gemset/gems/data_objects-0.10.15/lib/data_objects/connection.rb:79:in `initialize'
```

Ruby Version - `2.1.3`
OS - Mac - `10.10.1`

Can some one please get me a solution as I have spent a lot of time on it.

Comment: That suggests your username and password combination is wrong.

Comment: I didn't mention my username and password above. I was able to connect before ruby upgrade. This started happening only after upgrade.

Comment: How do you provide the username and password to the app? Where's the rest of the error stack trace?

Comment: In rails console if do User.first, I'm getting the above error. And I'm using database.yml to connect to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a problem with your database configuration. By the message I suspect you are using MySQL as database.

So instead of using sockets, maybe you are using host instead of sockets. Try something like this in your `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Also make sure you can access your database:

```
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE
```

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. Still getting same error.

Comment: @Temerario can you login in the command line: mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD  -D DATABASE ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I found my mistake. Recently the user name has been changed and I didn't update my branch.

Comment: @Temerario OK, I will update the answer, so you can accept it!